# How to serve both static and dynamic content via AWS cloudfront?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, digital-ocean

I have a site hosted on a digital ocean droplet which serves both static and dynamic content. The static content (e.g. /images, /js, /css, /fonts) is served from an s3 bucket with folders `/images, /js, /css, /fonts`
via cloudfront which has a path pattern behaviour of `Default (*)`. To use a custom url for this distribution i added an alternate name of `assets-dev.example.com` and added a cname record
in my DNS control panel which points assets-dev.example.com to the cloudfront distribution. This part all works fine.

Now I want to serve the rest of my site e.g. dev.example.com which also serves dynamic content via cloudfront.

I tried to set up a custom origin using domain `dev.example.com` and added another alternate name for the distribution of `dev.example.com`

However in my DNS control panel I have an A record pointing `dev.example.com` to my digital ocean droplet and get an error if I try to add a cname record with `dev.example.com` pointing to the cloudfront url.

So my questions are:

1. What's the correct way to configure the DNS settings so that dev.example.com is returning content from cloudfront which then gets it from my custom origin digital ocean droplet?
2. There is an AWS tutorial on how to serve dynamic content using ec2 and cloudfront (https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/getting-started/EC2/) but doesn't go into the detail of configuring the DNS settings and his set up doesn't cache any content so not sure purpose
   not caching content in his tutorial serves?
3. If I have 2 origins defined (s3 and digital ocean droplet) and two alternate name (assets-dev.example.com and dev.example.com) how would cloudfront know from which origin to serve content from?
   Note in my site the url to return assets is defined as https://assets-dev.example.com/js/test.js etc